# script to search for a string in logfiles on remote machines and copy the matched text

Tags: linux, ssh, grep, string-matching

I would like to write a script(on linux based systems) that does the following :

1. I have a list of remote machines say for e.g mc1, mc2, mc3 and so on
2. on each of those machines, i have a logfile say for e.g /var/log/mail.log
3. I have a unique-id with me
4. This unique-id will be present in only one logfile on any of those machines
5. Now, I have to search for this id in all those logfiles stored on those machines and get the matched line.

I am thinking of using bash/grep/ssh to do this, but dont know how :(
Can anyone please help me out to accomplish this :)

Comment: Narrow down the question.  Do you know how to get the files from the remote machines?  If not, ask that question.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
ssh user@mc1 -c "echo "Machine: mc1; grep $UNIQUE_ID /var/log/mail.log; echo ---------;"
ssh user@mc2 -c "echo "Machine: mc2; grep $UNIQUE_ID /var/log/mail.log; echo ---------;"
ssh user@mc3 -c "echo "Machine: mc3; grep $UNIQUE_ID /var/log/mail.log; echo ---------;"
ssh user@mc4 -c "echo "Machine: mc4; grep $UNIQUE_ID /var/log/mail.log; echo ---------;"
```